# Python make a hue color cycle

Tags: python, colors

How can I make a RGB color cycle in python? I only need the Hue value from an HSL wheel. I've tried lots of code but none worked. I'll include a small snippet down below.

```
r, g, b = r/255.0, g/255.0, b/255.0
mx = max(r, g, b)
mn = min(r, g, b)
df = mx-mn
if mx == mn:
    h = 0
elif mx == r:
    h = (60 * ((g-b)/df) + 360) % 360
elif mx == g:
    h = (60 * ((b-r)/df) + 120) % 360
elif mx == b:
    h = (60 * ((r-g)/df) + 240) % 360
```

although this return one hue color and I need it to cycle in between all the RGB colors. Is there anyone that can help with this?

Comment: [colorsys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/colorsys.html) is built in to Python, why not use that? You'd just convert an HSV value, where the hue is continuously increasing/decreasing, to an RGB value. You can just leave Saturation and Value at 1 or whatever and only change the hue.

Comment: How would a do/approach this?

Comment: That's a pretty broad question but I can write an answer that has an example of what I mean. It's really straightforward though with that library, via `rgb_to_hsv` and `hsv_to_rgb`.

Comment: Note "hue colour circle/wheel" (not cycle) doesn't represent all colours: colours are 3D. Usually on colour wheel you have an additional (or few sliders)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, a hue wheel only modifies hue, which is one of the axes. Saturation and Value are not changed here

Comment: @axon: but the requirement in the question is *I need it to cycle in between all the RGB colors*, so not just hue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can cycle through R, G and B values by just adjusting a hue. Increase `num_steps` to make the cycle slower and smoother; setting it any higher than ~1800 won't make things any smoother though. The code does one complete cycle, so you could loop it in order to have it be continuous:

```
import colorsys

num_steps = 20 # arbitrary
hue = 0.0
step_val = 1.0 / num_steps
for _ in range(num_steps):
    rgb = colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(hue, 1, 1)
    hue += step_val
    hue %= 1.0 # cap hue at 1.0
    r = round(rgb[0] * 255)
    g = round(rgb[1] * 255)
    b = round(rgb[2] * 255)
    rgb_ints = (r, g, b)
    print(rgb_ints)
```

Output:

```
(255, 0, 0)
(255, 77, 0)
(255, 153, 0)
(255, 230, 0)
(204, 255, 0)
(128, 255, 0)
(51, 255, 0)
(0, 255, 25)
(0, 255, 102)
(0, 255, 178)
(0, 255, 255)
(0, 179, 255)
(0, 102, 255)
(0, 25, 255)
(51, 0, 255)
(128, 0, 255)
(204, 0, 255)
(255, 0, 229)
(255, 0, 153)
(255, 0, 76)
```